# Trouble Referencing UIButton using NSMutableAttributedString in Instantiated View Controller

Tags: swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

As soon as my view controller loads, I am presented with a button (gray background with white font) that displays the text “Sto 1”. This is called in viewWillLayoutSubviews and the title is set using a NSMutableAttributedString. “Sto” is short for store.

For my application, I would like the user to be able to select the Sto 1 button and be able to store a number that is presented on a UILabel. I am able to grab the current number being displayed but I’m unable to update the text inside my Sto 1 button using NSMutableAttributedString. In other words I want to go from the button showing “Sto 1” to displaying some number (e.g., 12).

Thank you all for any help you may be able to provide me. I am still relatively new to Swift and I have been trying to resolve this issue over the past week.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var fontConstant = CGFloat()
var someRandomNumberDisplayedOnAUILabel = String(12)

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    fontConstant = 1
    let myString = "Sto 1"
    let myAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :  UIColor(red: 251/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 251/255.0, alpha: 1.0), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10 * fontConstant)]
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttributes)
    myButton.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255.0, green: 94/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}


@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :  UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10 * fontConstant)]
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: someRandomNumberDisplayedOnAUILabel, attributes: myAttributes)
    myButton.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 251/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 251/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}}
```

Comment: Does the background color change as expected when the button action is called?

Comment: The above code works in my recreated simplified project. However, it doesn’t work in my current project.l that involves a UIPageViewController.

Comment: Right, but if the background color doesn't change in your current project with the UIPageViewController, it might indicate that the `IBAction` isn't being called at all.

Comment: It is working. I know the IBAction is being called in my current project because I have a print statement within the IBAction that outputs what is in the UILabel. Therefore, the IBAction is being called as I can see the variable that holds the string on the UILabel in the output console. The setAttributedTitle() is not updating the UIButton text for whatever reason.

Comment: After some more debugging, I am now realizing the the UIButton title keeps showing up as nil after setting the title using setAttributedTitle(). Do you know why this may be?

Comment: I assume that moving to another view in the page view controller is deallocating the button outlet. You might be able to add the action to the button before losing the reference to it. See my second edit for some example code.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would use [setTitle(*:for:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) to change the text on a `UIButton`. But since you're working with an `NSMutableAttributedString` you will need the [setAttributedTitle(:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624012-setattributedtitle) function. I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
myButton.setAttributedTitle(myNSMutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
```

Heads up, though. You might need to call this function for the different control states and not just `.normal` otherwise you might see different text for an instant as the button is highlighted. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state) is a list of the control states.

**EDIT:**
I would try referencing the sender in the `IBAction` instead of `myButton`. This might be a quick fix:

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :  UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10 * fontConstant)]
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: someRandomNumberDisplayedOnAUILabel, attributes: myAttributes)

    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
        print("Error: sender was not a button")
        return
    }
    button.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 251/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 251/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

**EDIT #2:**
If you're losing the reference to your `IBOutlet` you might be able to work around that by assigning a selector to the button *before* you lose it. Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add the action to the button rather than holding on to the IBOutlet
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RideInProgressViewController.myAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func myAction(sender: Any) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
        print("Error: sender was not a button")
        return
    }

    let myAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :  UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10 * fontConstant)]
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: someRandomNumberDisplayedOnAUILabel, attributes: myAttributes)

    button.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 251/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 251/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I’m sorry if I was a little vague. I initially did use setAttributedTitle in viewWillLayoutSubviews, but later in the application when the user goes to press the button resetting the title by the buttons action using setAttributedTitle doesn’t work? Seems very odd. I will try to look into the control states some more, but I have tried using .normal and .selected and still haven’t got it to work.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the code that isn't producing the expected results?

Comment: Sure, what’s the best way to submit/link to a small project in Stack Overflow? I’m afraid my issue may reside in something from using a pageViewController. I tried recreating my issue in a new project with a single view controller and the button responded correctly.

Comment: It sounds like it might be an issue keeping the reference to the `UIButton`. Can you edit your question and add the lines of code relevant to the button such as the `IBOutlet`, the first setup for the button in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, and where you attempt to update the text with a new string?

Comment: I did. Thank you for the suggestion. I hope the new question title is suitable.